# Why are my COMMITs after SELECT-only transactions slow with PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I have a web app presenting data that's being generated by a separate process and stored in PostgreSQL, version 8.4. The backend is writing fairly continuously, but the majority of views in the web app execute nothing but read-only SELECT queries.

According to the New Relic Python agent, 30% of my view processing time is spent waiting for COMMITs to complete, and it's particularly bad in views that issued a lot of SELECT queries, even if they didn't modify any data.

I expected a transaction that had been read-only to have very little work to do during the commit phase. What is Postgres doing during COMMIT on these read-only queries?

I know I could turn off `synchronous_commit` for these transactions to hide the latency from the view, and I certainly don't care about durability for a read-only transaction, but I don't see why it should be necessary, and I'm concerned that doing so might mask a deeper misconfiguration.

Comment: Are the quries really read only? Postgres has nothing to commit on read only transaction.

Comment: I have a transaction here with a `SET TIME ZONE` and four `SELECT` statements, and the `COMMIT` took 456ms. Another transaction issued 22 `SELECT` statements, each taking 14ms or less, and then took 959ms to `COMMIT`.

Comment: A `SELECT` statement can call a function that can do some modifications. If you are sure, that no modifications are made in DB - try `SET TRANSACTION READ ONLY;` and see if something fails.

Comment: I would setup postgres logging and watch what sql is running on your database.

Comment: What version of PostgreSQL are you on?

Comment: @JustBob: I meant to mention that, thanks. I'm using Postgres 8.4.

Answer (score 5):

There are various clean up operations that need to be done to keep the database in good shape, and many of these are done by the first process that stumbles upon the opportunity, even if that process is only doing select queries.

These clean up operations can generate WAL records, which then trigger syncs upon commit.  So while the selects might be read-only on a user-visible level, behind the scenes they really are doing writes.

It should be possible to detect when all of the WAL operations done in a given transaction are from clean-up operations, and then automatically do the commit asynchronously in those cases.  But no one has gotten around to implementing this feature yet (or even cataloging all of the WAL call-sites which are in this category).

Comment: Huh. There'd be a higher probability of having cleanup work fall during a transaction the longer the transaction takes to complete, which seems consistent with the results I'm seeing. The longest transactions have the most time spent during commit. So what can I do to fix it? Is async commit my only option?

Comment: Are you talking about hint-bit setting - I didn't think that was logged?

Answer (score 1):

Comments are too short so here goes.  Capture some logs while you run code and take the guess work out of the equation.

Update postgresql.conf to have these settings.  You will need to restart postgre to get logging_collector to take.  You can and should remove these settings after you are done. So make sure to backup postgresql.conf before making any changes. Once you have a log file with the captured data I recommend using this to look at it if the log is more than a page or so http://dalibo.github.io/pgbadger/.

```
log_destination = 'stderr'
logging_collector = on
log_directory = 'pg_log'
log_filename = 'postgresql-%Y-%m-%d.log'
log_rotation_age = 0
client_min_messages = notice
log_min_messages = warning
log_min_error_statement = error
log_min_duration_statement = 0
log_checkpoints = on
log_connections = on
log_disconnections = on
log_duration = off
log_error_verbosity = verbose
log_hostname = on
log_line_prefix = '%t [%p]: [%l-1] db=%d,user=%u '
log_lock_waits = on
log_statement = 'none'
log_temp_files = 0
```

Comment: Another option would be to use [pg_stat_statements](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgstatstatements.html) to log and monitor the statements.

Comment: Out of curiosity when would you use this approach vs regular logging?  Would you say this is a more light weight approach, but provides less information?